# Can't use function when i run npm run start

Tags: node.js, electron, node-gyp

Hello I wanted to be able to use a c code with electron, so I used node api but when i run the command `npm run start`, the require() function seems to get stuck since the other functions after it do not run. I also have no errors when running this command. I don't understand why the functions in the index.js file are blocked.

Here is my code:

index.js :

`const server = require("./build/Release/server");`
`console.log(server.Server(12));`

`document.getElementById('h1-fs-s5').innerText = "12";`

server.c :

```
#include<node_api.h>

napi_value Server(napi_env env, napi_callback_info info){
    size_t argc=1;
    napi_value args[1];
    int64_t upper_limit;
    int64_t largest_prime;
    napi_value output;

    napi_get_cb_info(env,info,&argc,args,NULL,NULL);

    napi_get_value_int64(env,args[0],&upper_limit);
    largest_prime=upper_limit;
    napi_create_double(env,largest_prime,&output);
    return output;
}

napi_value init(napi_env env, napi_value exports)
{
    napi_value server;
    napi_create_function(env,NULL,0,Server,NULL,&server);

    napi_set_named_property(env, exports, "Server",server);

    return exports;
}

NAPI_MODULE(NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME,init);
```

binding.gyp :

```
{
    "variables": {
        "openssl_fips" : "0" 
    },
    "targets":[
        {
            "target_name":"server",
            "sources":[
                "server.c"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```